# Mostrar elementos de acordo com click

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Em minha view tenho 5 partials que devem ser renderizadas. Eu precisava que ao clicar uma é mostrada e as outras sejam ocultadas...

Está nesta estrutura:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#cliente">Cliente</a></li>
            <li><a href="#anamnese">Anamnese</a></li>
            <li><a href="#recordatorio">Recordatorio</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="cliente">
            @Html.Partial("_PartialCliente", Model)
        </div>

        <div id="anamnese">
            @Html.Partial("_PartialAnaminese", Model)
        </div>

        <div id="recordatorio">
            @Html.Partial("_PartialRecordatorio", Model)
            @Html.Partial("_PartialRefeicao", Model)
            @Html.Partial("_PartialQuestionarioFrequenciaAlimentar", Model)
        </div>
```

Como que eu poderia fazer isso? Ou seja, como eu poderia clicar na tab cliente e mostre somente a partial referente e as outras sejam ocultadas e da mesma forma pras outras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, podes sempre usar uma `hide` class juntamente com uma `partial`,
`<div id="recordatorio" class="partial hide">`
depois qualquer coisa como (pseudo-code):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.partial').map(function() { this.onClick = function() {
        this.classname.slice(this.classname.indexOf('hide'),1);
        // ... e o codigo para adicionar o 'hide' a todos os outros
    }; 
});
```

Basicamente, a cada clique num `partial` ele iria tirar o `hide` do proprio elemento e aplica-lo a todos os outros que nao tenham o `hide` mas sejam `partial`s.